# Refactoring the legacy code which is using '§' char in the code

Tags: c++, oracle

I have a legacy code (might be 20 years old) as shown below. Where they are using the `non ASCII '§'` char in the code.
First they are preparing a `SELECT` query and the `SELECT` query looks like this...

```
SELECT 'ERROR_ID=§' || ERROR_ID ||  '§'  || ' AND ' ||  'DAT=:' || ...
```

They are using below code while preparing the `SELECT` query.
    strcat(query, "§" );

From the **`SELECT` query result** which still contains the `'§'`, they are doing comparision as shown below and if `'§'` char is present in the char array, they are replacing it with `single quotes`.
Since they are using the `non ASCII char '§'` in the code, I have been repoted an issue where the `'§'` is not getting replaced with `single quotes` and they
are appearing as question marks `'?'` in the log file. Below is the code where they are doing the replace

```
len_before=strlen(file_str);
k=l=end=0;
while(end==0)
{
    if(file_str[k] == '\'') 
    {
        strcpy( result,(char*)&file_str[k]);
        file_str[k] = '\'';
        strcpy((char*)&file_str[k+1],result);
        k++;
    }
    else
    {
        if((char)file_str[k]=='§') // Replace '§' by single quotes.
        {
            strncpy((char*)&file_str[k],"'",1);
        }
    }
    k++;
    l++;
    if(l>len_before)
        end=1;
};
```

So I am refactoring the code to not to use the non ASCII char `'§'` with sequence of chars as say `("!-!")` for preparing the `SELECT` query as shown.

```
strcat(query, "!-!" );
```

And the result from the `SELECT` query I have to replace this sequence of chars `("!-!")` with single quotes. Below is the refactored code...

```
string replaceAll(string inputString, string stringToFind, string stringToReplace)
{
    int found = inputString.find(stringToFind);
    while (found != string::npos)
    {
        inputString.replace(found, stringToFind.length(), stringToReplace);
        found = inputString.find(stringToFind, found + stringToReplace.length());
    }
    return inputString;
}

{
    // First replace every occurance of single quotes with double single quotes.
    string myString(file_str);
    myString = replaceAll(myString, "\'", "\'\'");

    // Replace the sequence of chars "!-!" with single quotes.
    myString = replaceAll(myString, "!-!", "\'");
}
```

**Questions:**

- I would like to know if there are any pit falls which I need to look after?
- Which sequence of chars can be used instead of `"!-!"`?
- Is there any significane of char `'§'` (I believe that code is using `'§'` as a delimiter)in the code since they are connecting to the DB and fetching the data?

Comment: Why is the query written in a way that requires parsing delimited text? It looks like you are simply replacing one nasty hack with another nasty hack.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you using `std::`, surely you didn't put `using namespace std` somewhere in your code right?

I find your parameter names a bit confusing. `stringToReplace` is actually the replacement. The string you want to replace is `stringToFind`. Maybe use something like `replaceWith` or just `replacement` for the second parameter instead.

There is a type mismatch which your compiler should have caught (no warnings enabled?). The [return value of find is `size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

You can also pass the first argument as a reference and the other two as const reference.